# Unexpected json output structure from php array

Tags: php, json, multidimensional-array, arguments

I am trying to convert a dynamic data.  How to get this JSON from PHP:

```
/*JSON*/
{
   "122240cb-253c-4046-adcd-ae81266709a6": {
      "item": {
          "0": "3"
      }
   }
}
```

This is what I have done, but it's not working:

```
/*PHP*/

$json = array("122240cb-253c-4046-adcd-ae81266709a6"=> array(
    "item" => array($form_item)
));

echo json_encode($json, JSON_FORCE_OBJECT + JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

This is the result I am getting instead of the above.

```
{
"122240cb-253c-4046-adcd-ae81266709a6": {
    "0": {
        "item": 3
    }
}
```

Comment: your code is just working fine. it gives the exact output as you wanted.

Comment: I think you are confused the with the json lint data with normal one.

Comment: Your code works fine. Can you specify what error or output do you get in your case ?

Comment: @Thamaraiselvam I have updated the question with the result I am getting.

Comment: @mickmackusa what error message if I may ask?

Comment: @DavidAddoteye  Update the value of `$form_item`

Comment: What is in $form_item?

Comment: @Thamaraiselvam thank you. You are right. That is where the problem is coming problem. It is working now. Thanks again.

Comment: Great! Happy coding @DavidAddoteye

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, a bit of code to demonstrate what needs to be adjusted.

1. Move the `item` key up one level (out of the lowest subarray)
2. Quote-wrap your `$form_item` value to make it a string.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/nmZO3))

```
$form_item = 3;
$original_json = array("122240cb-253c-4046-adcd-ae81266709a6"=> array(
    array("item" => $form_item)
));
echo json_encode($original_json, JSON_FORCE_OBJECT + JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);

echo "\n---\n";

$form_item = "3";
$desired_json = array("122240cb-253c-4046-adcd-ae81266709a6"=> array(
    "item" => array($form_item)
));
echo json_encode($desired_json, JSON_FORCE_OBJECT + JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

Output:

```
{
    "122240cb-253c-4046-adcd-ae81266709a6": {
        "0": {
            "item": 3
        }
    }
}
---
{
    "122240cb-253c-4046-adcd-ae81266709a6": {
        "item": {
            "0": "3"
        }
    }
}
```

---

## Now onto the more interesting part that tripped me up at first glance...

You are using a syntax with the options parameters that I've never seen before and is not mentioned on the [json_encode() documentation page](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php).  You are listing multiple [json constants](http://php.net/manual/en/json.constants.php) and separating them with `+` instead of the pipes (`|`) like the manual demonstrates.

To explain why this is valid syntax, I must express what is happening "behind the scenes".

The constants are actually "bitmasks".  Each constant is assigned a number.

> JSON_HEX_TAG => 1
>   JSON_HEX_AMP => 2
>   JSON_HEX_APOS => 4
>   JSON_HEX_QUOT => 8
>   JSON_FORCE_OBJECT => 16
>   JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK => 32
>   JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES => 64
>   JSON_PRETTY_PRINT => 128
>   JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE => 256
>   JSON_PARTIAL_OUTPUT_ON_ERROR => 512
>   JSON_PRESERVE_ZERO_FRACTION => 1024

You see, these numbers are not arbitrarily assigned; each progressive number is deliberately twice the previous number.  Why? Because if you dare to list multiple `options`, you can write a single number that represents the sum of any two or more constants and you will never accidentally fall prey to a value collision.

What does this mean?  All of the following expressions produce the same output:

```
echo json_encode($json, JSON_FORCE_OBJECT | JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
echo json_encode($json, JSON_FORCE_OBJECT + JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
echo json_encode($json, 16 + 128);
echo json_encode($json, 144);
```

Want proof? ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/oEvel))

Comment: @David I have retracted my Off-topic: Typo close vote.  You are using a syntax that I hadn't come across before.  I am actually glad you did, because it gave me a reason to research the `options` constants that json uses.